# Параллезм/многопоточность/асинхронность

Tags: многопоточность, терминология, асинхронность, распараллеливание

Прочитал разные источники, но не уверен, что все правильно понимаю:

1. Многопоточность - достигается путем выполнения различных кусков кода, где за счет высокой скорости(кусочек там, кусочек там) складывается впечатление как будто это выполняется паралельно;
2. Параллельность - просто используются разные ядра процессора (да-да именно слово "ядро" я использую в этом термине, ничего другого не знаю и как еще может быть достигнуто не представляю);
3. Асинхронность - выполняется вне нашей программы (операционной системой, бд или любой другой программой).

P.S работаю на .Net